# How to open installed android app when i click a url in my email?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivateActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"           
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter >
            <data android:host="www.testlink.com.qa"  android:pathPrefix="/templates/home.aspx/" android:scheme="http"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

this is my code....its not working when click the link (www.testlink.com.qa) from my email.
but it work when i call from another app using  Uri.parse("http://www.testlink.com.qa/templates/home.aspx")

Comment: Its called deep linking, take a look http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
                <data android:host="www.testlink.com.qa" android:path="www.testlink.com.qa/templates/home.aspx" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Email link http://www.testlink.com.qa/templates/home.aspx

Comment: its not working when i give Email link as  http://www.testlink.com.qa/templates/home.aspx

Comment: when i click this link from my mail ,it shows option for select browser

Comment: If application is not installed then it open in browser

Comment: http://danielmuller.asia/2013/02/android-open-an-app-from-web-link-or-fallback-to-market/